# Object Detection - Server side - Technologies

Tags: image-processing, cloud

I am new to Image Processing. My goal is to detect round objects on the server side. Currently, i am trying to find the right technology in order to implement [this](http://foo.com) tutorial in the cloud (i use Heroku because it has free package).

I decided to investigate the abilities of NodeJS + OpenCV + Heroku, however, i saw that OpenCV addon for NodeJS lacks documentation and it is complicated to deploy it on Heroku.

Is there any other technology that can fulfill my goals instead of NodeJS (e.g. Python)?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is a rich Computer Vision library that contains the sorts of functions you'd need and has a Python implementation
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html